# Are there non-lagrangian field theories for massive Weyl spinors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, fermions, spinors, chirality

It is a well-known fact that a chiral fermion is massless, since the mass term involves both a right-handed and a left-handed field. If you have one chirality only there are no mass terms one can write down.

This does not immediately mean Weyl spinors are massless; just that there is no lagrangian for massive ones. But I can imagine that there are QFTs of massive chiral fermions which admit no lagrangian description at all, thus circumventing the obstruction. Is this possible? Or is there a more kinematical reason for masslessness, beyond impossibility for writing down suitable mass terms?

(For a long time people thought that there were no $\mathcal N=3$ supersymmetric theories because there is no lagrangian with that amount of supercharges. But more recently [people found](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06434) that $\mathcal N=3$ is indeed possible, but the theory is non-lagrangian.)